# Oracle perfromance joining 3 tables with sum aggregate function

Tags: oracle, performance, sum

I Have Three tables
Terms  ( id, isn,SentenceID,Term_Root,sentence_length) contains a full corpus ( more than 20 Million records ) 
User_Terms ( id,isn,SentenceID,Term_Roott,sentence_length) contains the user document info ( about 100000 records)
Correlations ( id, Term1, Term2, Correlation_Factor ) contains static data, that describes the correlation and similarity between any 2 terms (contains about 500000 records)

I want to find the similarity between the user document sentence and all the documents in the corpus. by joining user term and corpus term and find the correlation factor, and summing the result for each sentence
I used this Query

```
SELECT   tt.SENTENCEID ,tu.SENTENCEID,

       sum (c.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/greatest( tu.sentence_length,tt.sentence_length),
      tt.isn ,
      tu.isn  
  FROM CORRELATIONS c,
TERMS tt,
User_TERMS tu
 WHERE (tt.TERM_ROOT  = c.TERM1
AND tu.TERM_ROOT = c.TERM2 

  AND tu.ISN='22242')
   group by tt.SENTENCE_ID, tu.SENTENCE_ID, tt.isn, tu.isn,tu.sentence_length,tt.sentence_length
having 

      sum (c.CORRELATION_FACTOR)/greatest( tu.sentence_length,tt.sentence_length)>0.6;
```

this query takes more than 10 min. 
how can I rewrite it to be as fast as possible? what indexes do I need?

Edited : this is my explain plan:
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT||  2670 |   219K|  3864   (1)| 00:00:47 |

|*  1 |  FILTER         ||       |       |            |          |

|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY ||  2670 |   219K|  3864   (1)| 00:00:47 |

|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS || 53383 |  4379K|  3862   (1)| 00:00:47 |

|*  4 |     HASH JOIN   ||  1414 | 86254 |  1032   (1)| 00:00:13 |

|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN | INDEX5|  1425 | 31350 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |

|   6 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PLAG_TERM_CORRELATIONS4_UK1 |   563K|    20M|  1020   (1)| 
00:00:13 |

|*  7 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN     | PLAG_TERMS_INDEX1           |    38 |   874 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |

---

### Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

1 - filter(SUM("C"."CORRELATION_FACTOR")/GREATEST("TU"."SENTENCE_LENGTH","TT"."SENTENCE_LENGT
              H")>0.6)

4 - access("TU"."TERM_ROOT"="C"."TERM2")

5 - access("TU"."ISN"='22242')

7 - access("TT"."TERM_ROOT"="C"."TERM1")

Comment: Try adding indexes to columns you use in `where` clause and columns that are used in aggregates function

Comment: Without query plan it is hard to tell. You probably lack of some index as suggested in the previous comment. @Aramillo could you elaborate a little about indexing _" columns that are used in aggregates function"_ ? I don't understand why indexing `c.CORRELATION_FACTOR` would improve performances in the general case.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux sorry, you're rigth. That index is not necessary. I don't know what i was thinking.

Comment: yes, I created the indexes for all the col. in the where clause and aggregate functions, and still slow, I also used ( parallel hint , ffs hint ) no value added. I am trying to change the query. Is there any sugestion for better query? rewriting? using subquery ? what can I do?

Comment: I have no enough reputations to upload plan as image